# Sharepoint Remote Debugging

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I want to develop a remote event receiver for Sharepoint 2013 using Visual Studio 2013.

The development environment will be 2 computers. The first one will be the Sharepoint server and the second one will have visual studio. Both computers will be in the same LAN.

I have been reading articles explaining that remote debugging sharepoint apps require a windows azure service bus account.

I want to know if this requirement is only for apps running on azure or if is also required for remote debugging on a Local LAN server?

Please review the following article for reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220047%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

EDIT --> Sorry I just reread your question and noted that you are developing a remote event receiver.  I do not have experience with this so am not sure if there is a different way of approaching this.

I have always used a separate farm to develop on that has Visual Studio installed directly on the SharePoint server.

virtual server1 --> sharepoint + visual studio
virtual server2 --> sql server

I then work in an MSTSC window directly on the development server.

Most SharePoint solutions can then be F5 debugged.

For event receivers, you set a break point in the event receiver and build and deploy your code and then navigate in a separate browser (from your workstation or where ever) to the place in the site where the event receiver should activate.

In Visual Studio, use debug / attach to process to connect to the IIS worker process for your portal site.

Now in the web browser perform whatever action should trigger the event receiver (activating a feature, adding a list item etc..) and you should see the break point being hit in Visual Studio.

Hope this helps !!

(I am of the current understanding that it is not really possible to develop using a remote copy of Visual Studio, ie. one not installed on the SharePoint server.  Happy to be corrected by more experienced developers.)